# Microdata Testing Tool has error at phone?

Tags: html, google-search-console, microdata, structured-data

I have this example code (just the part needed here):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProfessionalService" lang="hu">
<head></head>
<body>
<section id="contact">
    <ul>
        <li>Tel.: <span  itemprop="telephone" id="tel"><a     "href="tel:+36305555555">06 (30) 5555555</a></span></li>

    </ul>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

When I validate this in [Google's Structured data testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) I got the proper data on the right. I see the number there. It is fine.
[image]

### **Here comes the problem:**

When I use the first markup **in Webmaster Tools, Google considers this as a link that gives it 404 error**, as there is no page like +36305555555. And this is a problem.

I read the solution is putting the intemprop in the `<a>` tag like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProfessionalService" lang="hu">
<head></head>
<body>
<section id="contact">
    <ul>
        <li>Tel.: <span id="tel"><a "href="tel:+36305555555" itemprop="telephone">06 (30) 5555555</a></span></li>

    </ul>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

But in this case the testing tool gives me this:
[image]

So in one case Google says *"ok this is cool as structured data, I see your phone number BUT it is an error 404 so don't do it"*. In the other case it says: *"It is a phone number with an URL BUT you are fine, you have no 404 errors"*.

**What to do in this situation?**

Comment: Wouldn’t Google also consider this "a link that gives it 404 error" even if you would not use Microdata at all?

Answer (score 0):

Note: it’s `href`, not `"href`.

This is valid HTML5+Microdata and appropriate use of the Schema.org vocabulary:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProfessionalService">
  <span itemprop="telephone">
    <a href="tel:+36305555555">06 (30) 5555555</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

If you’d specify the `telephone` property on the `a` element instead, the property value would be the value of the `href` attribute, but Schema.org [currently expects text](http://schema.org/telephone), not a URL, so your solution with the additional `span` is correct.

I don’t know Google Webmaster Tools, but I think it’s odd that they would try to resolve a `tel` URI (which would never work). Anyway, I can’t see why this should stop you using this markup.

Comment: I messed up the example. The 404 error stuff still true sadly